# Excluding numbers from range() function

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, range

I'm populating a select box dynamically with numbers from 20 to 60
using range(20, 60).

```
<select name="rangenumbers">
    <?php $range = range(20, 60);
        foreach ($range as $range) {
            echo '<option value="'.$range.'">'.$range.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
 </select>
```

And I have a function that return an array of numbers like

```
$a = array(25, 30 , 31, 50);
```

I need to populate that select box with numbers from 20 to 60 excluding numbers in the array : 25, 30, 31, 50.

Comment: `if ($range == 25) /* for example */ { //do nothing } else { //do whatever }`. Or ever better `if (in_array($range, $a))...`

Comment: try :- `<select name="rangenumbers">
<?php $a = array(25, 30 , 31, 50);?>
    <?php $range = range(20, 60);
        foreach ($range as $range) {
  if(!in_array($range,$a)){
            echo '<option value="'.$range.'">'.$range.'</option>';
   }
        }
    ?>
 </select>`  Output:- `http://prntscr.com/7cm5q6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `array_diff()` function:

```
<?php
$range = range(20, 60);
$a = array(25, 30 , 31, 50);

// the array_diff() function returns the values in the "$range" array
// that are not present in the array of "$a".
$allRanges = array_diff($range, $a);

foreach ($allRanges as $range) {
    echo '<option value="'.$range.'">'.$range.'</option>';
}
?>
```